# hortonworks sandbox connection refuse

Tags: hadoop, networking, hdfs, ambari

i just start to learn `hadoop` with `hortonworks` `sandbox`

i have HDP 2.3 on a virtualBox and in the setting i have a `Bridged Adapter` network and a NAT,

when i start the machine everything is ok i can do some `hadoop` command i can connect the `Ambari` at `127.0.0.1:8080` 
but when i run the script in `/etc/lib/hue/tools/start_scripts/gen_hosts.sh`
to generate  hosts with a different ip address every thing going wrong and i can't execute a simple `hadoop` command like `hadoop fs -ls /user`
i get this error

```
ls: Call From sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.24.244.85 to sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

as i said i just started to learn `hadoop` and i am not a network expert so i will preciate any help

thank you.

Comment: This is a DNS issue most likely. What is the output of the following two commands on the vm? `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that you have to restart the services ( `HDFS,MapReduce,Hbase`,..) from 
`Ambari` when you generate a host.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: 8020 is the port used by data node service,

Comment: Thanks! Restarting all the services would simply fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

turn on name NameNode  /  HDFS it will work